# How can i combine two similar php codes into one?

Tags: php

I got the following code:

```
<?php
// If user access item through link
if(isset($_POST["v"])) {
    require "connect.php";
    $v = $_POST['v'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE videoID=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo'Sql Error';
        exit();
    }
    else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $v);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && !preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $v)) { ?>

            <div class="img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $row['link']; ?>');"></div>
            <center><h1>Title <?php echo $row['Title']; ?> exists</h1></center>
            
            <?php exit();
        }
        else { ?>

            <center><h1>Title does not exist</h1></center>
            
            <?php exit();
        }
    }
}
// If user clicks on item
if(isset($_POST["itemid"])) {
    require "connect.php";
    $itemid = $_POST['itemid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE videoID=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo'Sql Error';
        exit();
    }
    else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $itemid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && !preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $itemid)) { ?>

            <div class="img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $row['link']; ?>');"></div>
            <center><h1>Title <?php echo $row['Title']; ?> exists</h1></center>
            
            <?php exit();
        }
        else { ?>

            <center><h1>Title does not exist</h1></center>
            
            <?php exit();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see both of the Isset if's are very similar, i am wondering if there is a solutions that combines the two so that i don't have to write the same results two times, also if anyone wanna give feedback on sql injection security on my code that would be welcomed!

This is also my first question on here so if you need me to elaborate on something please let me  know.

Comment: You can use or operator in the if statement and check for null values in $v and $itemid as per your preference.

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick answer! Is there a way to combine both of the "POSTs" into the same $ or would that create some sort of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `||` operator in `if` statement as follows and using a ternary operator to get whether the user accessed item through link or through click:

```
<?php
// If user access item through link
if(isset($_POST["v"]) || isset($_POST["itemid"])) {
    require "connect.php";
    //user ternary operator to check whether user accessed the item through link or click
    $var = isset($_POST['v'])?$_POST['v']:$_POST['itemid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE videoID=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo'Sql Error';
        exit();
    }
    else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $var);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && !preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $var)) { ?>

            <div class="img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $row['link']; ?>');"></div>
            <center><h1>Title <?php echo $row['Title']; ?> exists</h1></center>
            
            <?php exit();
        }
        else { ?>

            <center><h1>Title does not exist</h1></center>
            
            <?php exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah both seems to be similar except the POST parameter, Why don't you use a function which will handle your both the isset conditions!

Somewhat like this,

```
function funcName($param){

   require "connect.php";
//$v = $_POST['v'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE videoID=?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo'Sql Error';
    exit();
}
else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && !preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $v)) { ?>

        <div class="img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $row['link']; ?>');"></div>
        <center><h1>Title <?php echo $row['Title']; ?> exists</h1></center>
        
        <?php exit();
    }
    else { ?>

        <center><h1>Title does not exist</h1></center>
        
        <?php exit();
    }
}

}
```

then,

```
    if(isset($_POST["v"])) {

     $param = $_POST["v"];
     funcName($param);

}


if(isset($_POST["itemid"])) {

 $param = $_POST["itemid"];
     funcName($param);

}
```